# Changing a column type to centered

Tags: tables, arrays

I am trying to change this code in the DYI calendar

```
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\hfill\normalfont\footnotesize}p{\WkdayColWidthMonthTblYC}<{\hspace*{0.5em}}@{\extracolsep\fill}}
```

to make the column centered, but I don't know how to approach it without changing the base column type (that is, p) itself.

Comment: Have you tried using `>{\centering\arraybackslash}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up

```
\newcolumntype{W}[1]{>{\normalfont\footnotesize\centering}p{#1}}
```

and invoke it as

```
W{\WkdayColWidthMonthTbl‌​YC}
```

in a tabular-like environment.

If hyphenation of words is to be permitted, `\centering` won't do the job. Instead, load the `ragged2e` package as well and issue the instruction

```
\newcolumntype{W}[1]{>{\normalfont\footnotesize\Centering}p{#1}}
```

i.e., use `\Centering` instead of `\centering`.

Comment: I seem to get a bunch of underfull hboxes doing this, which messed up the formatting. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: One column specification, all by itself, cannot generate underfull (or overfull) boxes. Please tell us what else is going on in the table. E.g., what is the table's overall width? Do also give an idea how the length `\WkdayColWidthMonthTbl‌​YC` is set.

Comment: Oh, I realized that it's not an issue with the column itself--I accidentally left too many `\hfill` commands in the contents of the table which caused that.